# Alinhamento de imagem a direita da div no Bootstrap

Tags: css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Eu sei o que é alinhamento central e center-block no bootstrap, mas gostaria de saber como alinho uma imagem a direita de uma div? Não estou conseguindo coloca a imagem do telefone do lado do número, tenho que deixar os dois números no centro da página.

Vou colocar o código para entenderem melhor:

```css
footer{ margin-top:20px;}

.telefone{ width:45%; float:left; margin-right:10%;}
.telefone img{ float:right; }
.telefone p{font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif; font-size:1.5em; font-stretch:normal; font-weight:bold; padding:5px; float:right;}
.whatsapp{ width:45%; float:left;}
.whatsapp img{ float:left; margin-right:10px;}
.whatsapp p{font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif; font-size:1.5em; font-stretch:normal; font-weight:bold; padding:5px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<address>
  <div class="telefone text-right">
   <img src="imagens/telefone.png" class="img-responsive" />
    <p>(85) 8743.1561</p>
  </div>
  <div class="whatsapp">
   <img src="imagens/whatsapp.png" class="img-responsive" />
    <p>(85) 8118-9716</p>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div>Av. Major Assis, 2315 - Vila Velha - Fortaleza - Ceará</div>
</address>

<address>
  <strong>Full Name</strong><br>
  <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></div><a href="mailto:#">first.last@example.com</a>
</address>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Já tentou a classe pull-right ?

Comment: Já não está alinhada à direita?

Comment: André Ribeiro não, o telefone é para fica do lado da imagem! assim está errado

Comment: Nos estilos da tag P, tente colocar display:block-inline;

Comment: Algumas destas respostas lhe atenderam?

Comment: Você sabe que pode aceitar respostas? Veja em [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Você pode aceitar uma resposta por pergunta que fez. Pode até aceitar a sua resposta se foi a que melhor ajudou você.

Answer (score 2):

Simples, inverta a ordem dos elementos!

A classe `text-right` está fazendo com que todos os elementos filhos dela seja alinhados para a direita, fazendo com que a ordem destes se inverta.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```css
footer{ margin-top:20px;}

.telefone{ width:45%; float:left; margin-right:10%;}
.telefone img{ float:right; }
.telefone p{font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif; font-size:1.5em; font-stretch:normal; font-weight:bold; padding:5px; float:right;}
.whatsapp{ width:45%; float:left;}
.whatsapp img{ float:left; margin-right:10px;}
.whatsapp p{font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif; font-size:1.5em; font-stretch:normal; font-weight:bold; padding:5px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<address>
  <div class="telefone text-right">
    <p>(85) 8743.1561</p>
    <img src="imagens/telefone.png" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="whatsapp">
   <img src="imagens/whatsapp.png" class="img-responsive" />
    <p>(85) 8118-9716</p>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div>Av. Major Assis, 2315 - Vila Velha - Fortaleza - Ceará</div>
</address>

<address>
  <strong>Full Name</strong><br>
  <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></div><a href="mailto:#">first.last@example.com</a>
</address>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Não sei se será esse o problema... Esperemos a ver o que diz o AP.

Comment: Segundo a minha interpretação da pergunta dele, esta é a resposta, porém, não sei explicar exatamente o porque a classe `text-right`está fazendo isso com seus elementos filhos. =/

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a classe `pull-right` na div/img que queira colocar a direita ou diretamente no css `float:right`

Exemplo:

```
<div class="telefone text-right">
<img src="imagens/telefone.png" class="img-responsive pull-right" />
<p>(85) 8743.1561</p>
```

Comment: @rrnan, irei colocar

Comment: @rrnan, o deslocamento estará limitado ao tamanho da div, a imagem irá ficar colada no lado direito da div

Comment: Obrigado pela edição.